# write each line as it's processed using for-loop in python, but only writing the first line

Tags: python, csv, read-write

I have some code that I am trying to optimize to be more efficient.  One part of that is to process my file and after each line is processed, immediately write it to `csv`.  This is ideal as then I am not wasting memory by processing the data, then loading the data into a list to write out the entire list.  If I add the entire processed data to a list, I can write it to `csv` without trouble, as shown below, under `# write folded_data to csv`:

**Note: the code under #data processing is solid, and I just need help writing out each row as it's processed.**

```
# data processing
seen = set()
folded_data = []
for u in name_nodes:
#    seen=set([u]) # print both u-v, and v-u
    seen.add(u) # don't print v-u
    unbrs = set(B[u])
    nbrs2 = set((n for nbr in unbrs for n in B[nbr])) - seen
    for v in nbrs2:
        vnbrs = set(B[v])
        common = unbrs & vnbrs
        weight = len(common)
        row = u, v, weight
        folded_data.append(row)

# write folded_data to csv
with ('out_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(folded_data)
```

However, when I try and write out each `row` as it's processed, I only get the first line in 'out_file.csv'.

```
# data processing
seen = set()
for u in name_nodes:
    # seen=set([u]) # print both u-v, and v-u
    seen.add(u) # don't print v-u
    unbrs = set(B[u])   
    nbrs2 = set((n for nbr in unbrs for n in B[nbr])) - seen
    for v in nbrs2:
        vnbrs = set(B[v])
        common = unbrs & vnbrs
        weight = len(common)
        row = u, v, weight
        # write row for each line to csv
        with open('out_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I've tried moving my writing code around to make this work as I would like it to, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize for speed or memory?

Comment: @mattingly890 - primarily memory, as it is currently, trying to load everything into a list, and write out the list, I run out of memory.  Although making it run faster isn't such a bad thing either! :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you're getting the *first* line, you're getting the *last* line. For each line you write out, you're reopening the file, erasing the previous contents. Put the file open and csv writer creation outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about "wasting" memory unless your program asks for (e.g.) greater than 1/2 of the system memory.  If your CSV is in the multi-gigabyte range (or bigger) then this is a concern.

If your csv is not this large,  your file will end up in the OS file cache in memory, unless you have some non-standard kernel settings.

To do it the "efficient" way (i.e. to not explicitly store your data in memory), you need to open the file before the for loop.

Comment: the file that I'm trying to write out is roughly 3/4 of my system memory.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of @etep and @MarkRansom!  I have to open the file and define `writer` before the entire `for-loop`.

```
# open file and define writer
with open('out_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # data processing
    seen = set()
    for u in name_nodes:
    #    seen=set([u]) # print both u-v, and v-u
        seen.add(u) # don't print v-u
        unbrs = set(B[u])
        nbrs2 = set((n for nbr in unbrs for n in B[nbr])) - seen
        for v in nbrs2:
            vnbrs = set(B[v])
            common = unbrs & vnbrs
            weight = len(common)
            row = u, v, weight
            # write row for each record
            writer.writerow(row)
```